# WinHttpSetOption() failed set TLSv1.2 with error code ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to set `TLSv1.1 or v1.2` from C++ (Win) code using `cpprest` API calls as mentioned. But `WinHttpSetOption()` is failing with error `ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE` (12018).

OS:Windows(7/8)

1. Tried to set TLSv1.1 and TLS1.2 from registry setting did not work.
2. Tried to get OpenSLL but opensll1.0.1(which supports TLS1.1 and more) is not available for windows.
3. Tried to get other than native handle did not find API

```
auto func = [&](web::http::client::native_handle handle){
    BOOL win32Result{ FALSE };
    DWORD secure_protocols{ WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_1
        | WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2 };
    win32Result = ::WinHttpSetOption(handle,
        WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS,
        &secure_protocols,
        sizeof(secure_protocols));
    if (FALSE == win32Result) {
        std::cout << "Can not set TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2." << std::endl;
        auto err = GetLastError();
        CString cstr;
        cstr.Format(_T("err = %d"),err);
        AfxMessageBox(cstr);
    }
};
config.set_validate_certificates(false);
config.set_nativehandle_options(func);
```

Please help me to set TLSv1.1 or v1.2 using C++ REST API. Or 
how to make `WinHttpSetOption()` successful.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1 is not *available* for Windows ? Not that you would want that version, as 1.0.2 has a considerably vulnerability fix list, did you actually fetch it and try to build it yourself from [their github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig pre-built DLLs for OpenSSL 1.0.2 are available for Windows. They are even linked to on OpenSSL's wiki: [Binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm aware of that. I was simply pointing out that if you really want 1.0.1 for Windows, it can always be built if the need warrants.

Answer (score 2):

Using WinHttpOpen we can get "session handle" which can be passed to WinHttpSetOption().
This resolve the error "ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE ".

```
HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"<Application name>",
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
```

Though i am setting the TLS version to 1.2/1.1. Still my "http_request" is using TLSv1.0 which is default in Windows 7/8.1.(This is can confirm using wireshark)

Can any one let me know why "http_request" still using TLS1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing this update:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

"This update provides support for Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in Windows Server 2012, Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1), and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1."